# Mongo DB aggregation group performance

Tags: c#, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am pretty new to mongo DB and experimenting with it for one of our applications. We are trying to implement CQRS and query part we are trying to use node.js and command part we are implementing through c#.

One of my collections might have millions of documents in it. We would have a `scenarioId` field and each scenario can have around two million records.

Our use case is to compare these two scenarios data and do some mathematical operation on the each field of scenarios.
For example, each scenario can have a property `avgMiles` and I would like to compute the difference of this property and users should be able to filter on this difference value. As my design is to keep both scenarios data in single collection i am trying to do group by scenario id and further project it.

My sample structure of a document would look like below.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac05dc58ff6cd3054d5654c"), 
    "origin" : {
        "code" : "0000", 
    }, 
    "destination" : {
        "code" : "0001", 
    }, 
    "currentOutput" : {
        "avgMiles" : 0.15093020854848138, 
    },
    "scenarioId" : NumberInt(0), 
    "serviceType" : "ECON"
}
```

When I group I would group it based on `origin.code` and `destination.code` and `serviceType` properties.

My aggregate pipeline query looks like this:

```
  db.servicestats.aggregate([{$match:{$or:[{scenarioId:0}, {scenarioId:1}]}},
    {$sort:{'origin.code':1,'destination.code':1,serviceType:1}},
    {$group:{
      _id:{originCode:'$origin.code',destinationCode:'$destination.code',serviceType:'$serviceType'},
          baseScenarioId:{$sum:{$switch: {
                branches: [
                  {
                    case: { $eq: [ '$scenarioId', 1] },
                    then: '$scenarioId'
                  }],
                default: 0
                  }
        }},
        compareScenarioId:{$sum:{$switch: {
                branches: [
                  {
                    case: { $eq: [ '$scenarioId', 0] },
                    then: '$scenarioId'
                  }],
                default: 0
                  }
        }},
            baseavgMiles:{$max:{$switch: {
                branches: [
                  {
                    case: { $eq: [ '$scenarioId', 1] },
                    then: '$currentOutput.avgMiles'
                  }],
                default: null
                  }
        }},
        compareavgMiles:{$sum:{$switch: {
                branches: [
                  {
                    case: { $eq: [ '$scenarioId', 0] },
                    then: '$currentOutput.avgMiles'
                  }],
                default: null
                  }
        }}
    }
    },
    {$project:{scenarioId:
      { base:'$baseScenarioId',
        compare:'$compareScenarioId'
      },
    avgMiles:{base:'$baseavgMiles', comapre:'$compareavgMiles',diff:{$subtract :['$baseavgMiles','$compareavgMiles']}}
      } 
    },
    {$match:{'avgMiles.diff':{$eq:0.5}}},
    {$limit:100}
    ],{allowDiskUse: true} )
```

My group pipeline stage would have 4 million documents going in it. Can you please suggest how I can improve the performance of this query?

I have an index on the fields used in my group by condition and I have added a sort pipeline stage to help group by to perform better.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

As group by is not workin in my case i have implemented left outer join using $lookup and the query would look like below.

```
    db.servicestats.aggregate([
{$match:{$and :[ {'scenarioId':0}
  //,{'origin.code':'0000'},{'destination.code':'0001'}
  ]}},
//{$limit:1000000},
{$lookup: { from:'servicestats',
  let: {ocode:'$origin.code',dcode:'$destination.code',stype:'$serviceType'},
  pipeline:[
  {$match: {
                  $expr: { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$scenarioId", 1 ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$origin.code",  "$$ocode" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$destination.code",  "$$dcode" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$serviceType",  "$$stype" ] },
                       ]
                    }

              }
  },
  {$project: {_id:0, comp :{compavgmiles :'$currentOutput.avgMiles'}}},
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$comp" } }
  ],
  as : "compoutputs"
}},
{
          $replaceRoot: {
             newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects:[
                   {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                         "$$ROOT.compoutputs",
                         0
                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      origin: "$$ROOT.origin",
                      destination: "$$ROOT.destination",
                      serviceType: "$$ROOT.serviceType",
                      baseavgmiles: "$$ROOT.currentOutput.avgMiles",
                      output: '$$ROOT'
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       },
       {$limit:100}
])
```

the above query performance is good and returns in 70 ms.

But in my scenario i need a full outer join to be implemented which i understood mongo does not support as of now and implemented using $facet pipeline as below

```
    db.servicestats.aggregate([
{$limit:1000},
{$facet: {output1:[
  {$match:{$and :[ {'scenarioId':0}
  ]}},
{$lookup: { from:'servicestats',
  let: {ocode:'$origin.code',dcode:'$destination.code',stype:'$serviceType'},
  pipeline:[
  {$match: {
                  $expr: { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$scenarioId", 1 ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$origin.code",  "$$ocode" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$destination.code",  "$$dcode" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$serviceType",  "$$stype" ] },
                       ]
                    }

            }
  },
  {$project: {_id:0, comp :{compavgmiles :'$currentOutput.avgMiles'}}},
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$comp" } }
  ],
  as : "compoutputs"
}},
//{
//          $replaceRoot: {
//             newRoot: {
//                $mergeObjects:[
//                   {
//                      $arrayElemAt: [
//                         "$$ROOT.compoutputs",
//                         0
//                      ]
//                   },
//                   {
//                      origin: "$$ROOT.origin",
//                      destination: "$$ROOT.destination",
//                      serviceType: "$$ROOT.serviceType",
//                      baseavgmiles: "$$ROOT.currentOutput.avgMiles",
//                      output: '$$ROOT'
//                   }
//                ]
//             }
//          }
//       }
  ],
  output2:[
    {$match:{$and :[ {'scenarioId':1}
  ]}},
{$lookup: { from:'servicestats',
  let: {ocode:'$origin.code',dcode:'$destination.code',stype:'$serviceType'},
  pipeline:[
  {$match: {
                  $expr: { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$scenarioId", 0 ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$origin.code",  "$$ocode" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$destination.code",  "$$dcode" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$serviceType",  "$$stype" ] },
                       ]
                    }

            }
  },
  {$project: {_id:0, comp :{compavgmiles :'$currentOutput.avgMiles'}}},
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$comp" } }
  ],
  as : "compoutputs"
}},
//{
//          $replaceRoot: {
//             newRoot: {
//                $mergeObjects:[
//                   {
//                      $arrayElemAt: [
//                         "$$ROOT.compoutputs",
//                         0
//                      ]
//                   },
//                   {
//                      origin: "$$ROOT.origin",
//                      destination: "$$ROOT.destination",
//                      serviceType: "$$ROOT.serviceType",
//                      baseavgmiles: "$$ROOT.currentOutput.avgMiles",
//                      output: '$$ROOT'
//                   }
//                ]
//             }
//          }
//       },
       {$match :{'compoutputs':{$eq:[]}}}

  ]
  }
}




       ///{$limit:100}
])
```

But facet performance is very bad. Any further ideas to improve this are most welcome.

Comment: What happens if you don't set `allowDiskUse`? Does the aggregation still works? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Mongo throws error saying $group stage exceeded 100 MB limit. we ran this test with 64GB RAM

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7):

In general, there are three things that can cause slow queries:

1. The query is not indexed, cannot use indexes efficiently, or the schema design is not optimal (e.g. highly nested arrays or subdocuments) which means that MongoDB must do some extra work to arrive at the relevant data.
2. The query is waiting for something slow (e.g. fetching data from disk, writing data to disk).
3. Underprovisioned hardware.

In terms of your query, there may be some general suggestions regarding query performance:

- Using `allowDiskUse` in an aggregation pipeline means that it is possible that the query will be using disk for some its stages. Disk is frequently the slowest part of a machine, so if it's possible for you to avoid this, it will speed up the query.
- Note that an aggregation query is limited to 100MB memory use. This is irrespective of the amount of memory you have.
- The `$group` stage cannot use indexes, because an index is tied to a document's location on disk. Once the aggregation pipeline enters a stage where the document's physical location is irrelevant (e.g. the `$group` stage), an index cannot be used anymore.
- By default, the WiredTiger cache is ~50% of RAM, so a 64GB machine would have a ~32GB WiredTiger cache. If you find that the query is very slow, it is possible that MongoDB needed to go to disk to fetch the relevant documents. Monitoring `iostats` and checking disk utilization % during the query would provide hints toward whether enough RAM is provisioned.

Some possible solutions are:

- Provision more RAM so that MongoDB doesn't have to go to disk very often.
- Rework the schema design to avoid heavily nested fields, or multiple arrays in the document.
- Tailor the document schema to make it easier for you to query the data in it, instead of tailoring the schema to how you think the data should be stored (e.g. avoid heavy normalization inherent in relational database design model).
- If you find that you're hitting the performance limit of a single machine, consider sharding to horizontally scale the query. However, please note that sharding is a solution that would require careful design and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying above that you'd like to group by `scenarioId` which, however, you don't. But that is probably what you should be doing to avoid all the switch statements. Something like this might get you going:

```
db.servicestats.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        scenarioId: { $in: [ 0, 1 ] }
    }
}, {
    $sort: { // not sure if that stage even helps - try to run with and without
        'origin.code': 1,
        'destination.code': 1,
        serviceType: 1
    }
}, {
    $group: { // first group by scenarioId AND the other fields
        _id: {
            scenarioId: '$scenarioId',
            originCode: '$origin.code',
            destinationCode: '$destination.code',
            serviceType: '$serviceType'
        },
        avgMiles: { $max: '$currentOutput.avgMiles' } // no switches needed
    },
}, {
    $group: { // group by the other fields only so without scenarioId
        _id: {
            originCode: '$_id.originCode',
            destinationCode: '$_id.destinationCode',
            serviceType: '$_id.serviceType'
        },
        baseScenarioAvgMiles: {
            $max: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $eq: [ '$_id.scenarioId', 1 ] },
                    then: '$avgMiles',
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        },
        compareScenarioAvgMiles: {
            $max: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $eq: [ '$_id.scenarioId', 0 ] },
                    then: '$avgMiles',
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
}, {
    $addFields: { // compute the difference
        diff: {
            $subtract :[ '$baseScenarioAvgMiles', '$compareScenarioAvgMiles']
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        'avgMiles.diff': { $eq: 0.5 }
    }
}, {
    $limit:100
}], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

Beyond that I would suggest you use the power of [db.collection.explain().aggregate(...)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html) to find the right indexing and tune your query.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. But my query returns still takes 100 secs. where as expected performance is below 1 sec. Not sure if i will be able to achieve that performance